# Create a function such that:

Tags: functions

$f(3) = 0$, $f$ has a horizontal asymptote at $y = 2$, $f$ has vertical asymptotes at $x = 4$ and $x = -4$ and $f(0) = 1$. Basically, write a function for a graph that will match these criteria.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! What have you tried? Where are you struggling? Are there any constraints on $f$ (like continuity outside of $4,-4$)? Homework-style questions that don't show that you already put any effort in will usually not produce helpful answers on this site

Comment: And, posting imperatives "Solve this (for me), Simplify this (for me), Write a function... (for me)," aren't questions. It is rude to assign users here (all volunteers) the work *you've" been assigned. As CPCH suggests, you need to meet us half-way.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the asymptotes, a good candidate is any function of the form
$$f(x) = 2 + \frac{ax+b}{(x-4)(x+4)}.$$
Notice this has division by zero when $x=\pm4$, which gives you the desired vertical asymptotes, and also when $x\to\pm\infty$, the value of $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $2$; this is what it means to have a horizontal asymptote at $y=2$. (More precisely, $f(x) = 2 + O(\frac1x) \sim 2$.)

Now for the other two requirements, you can substitute $x=3$ and $x=0$ into $f(x)$ so that $f(3)=0$ and $f(0)=1$ give you simultaneous equations in $a$ and $b$, where you should find that $a=-\frac23$ and $b=16$. Thus the function
$$f(x) = 2 + \frac{-\frac23x+16}{(x-4)(x+4)}$$
which simplifies to
[$$f(x)=\frac{2 (x-3) (3 x+8)}{3 \left(x^2-16\right)}$$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/llo5edkyvb)
satisfies all the requirements.

Comment: Please refrain from answering "do it for me imperatives".

Answer (score 0):

Here's some guidance for answering this for yourself: try coming up with some functions that satisfy each requirement individually, then see if we can combine them in a way that doesn't break anything:

1. $f(3) = 0$. We could take the zero function, but that would likely cause problems with the combining, so instead, we'll look for something that's *only* zero at $3$.
2. A vertical asymptote at $x = 4$. The obvious function here has no problems.
3. A vertical asymptote at $x = -4$. Again, choose the obvious function.

At this point, you can combine these in a fairly obvious way to get a function that satisfies all three properties. I'll call that function $g$.

4. You can then modify $g$ to get some new function $h$ satisfying your first four requirements by just scaling it in $y$, assuming that $g$ has neither a zero nor an asymptote at $x = 0$. Otherwise, fix that first.
5. A horizontal asymptote at $y = 2$. First, make sure $h$ has a horizontal asymptote somewhere. If it's at $2$ already, you're done. If it's at some $c \neq 2$, construct a function $k$ which (a) is zero at $0$, (b) is zero at $3$, and (c) has a horizontal asymptote at $2 - c$, then take $f = h + k$. Points (a) and (b) are fairly easy: proceed as in (1) above. For (c), first make it have a horizontal asymptote somewhere other than $y = 0$, then scale it in $y$ to put the asymptote in the right place.